# Building .Net Core 3.0 app using Nix on macOS fails with permissions error

Tags: macos, .net-core-3.0, nix

I'm trying to build [FVim](https://github.com/yatli/fvim) on macOS using Nix. Because the version of the SDK available in Nixpkgs is 2.2.401 I wrote an overlay which successfully installs .Net Core 3.0 on my system:

```
self: super: {
  dotnet-sdk = super.dotnet-sdk.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
    version = "3.0.101";
    netCoreVersion = "3.0.1";
    system = "x86_64-darwin";
    src = super.fetchurl {
      url = "https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/${version}/${super.dotnet-sdk.pname}-${version}-osx-x64.tar.gz";
      sha512 = "3d01a586ab92f9386b13796a2307d77e35ec6932c0f97e0c8bfd87f4198890a302722f1e49d68a39d8b51e626eb5c4b3cbffd9ac8fbaf330b40d043c0a4c9a3e";
    };
    meta.platforms = super.stdenv.lib.platforms.darwin;
    buildPhase = ''
      runHook preBuild
      echo -n "dotnet-sdk version: "
      ./dotnet --version
      runHook postBuild
    '';
  });
}
```

But when I try to build FVim it fails:

```
error MSB4018: The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly. [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018: System.Unauthorized AccessException: Access to the path '/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/FVim' is denied. [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:  ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 error Rewriter) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Win 32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(String path, FileMode mode, String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fspro j]
error MSB4018:    at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(String path) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateAppHost>g__RewriteAppHost|0() [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.RetryUtil.RetryOnIOError(Action func) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFilePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore() [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/fvim.fsproj]
```

I'm pretty sure I have access to `/Users/tae/Projects/fvim/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/FVim`, so I thought the problem was related to `BundleExtraction` as pointed out [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7940), but neither `$TMPDIR` nor `$DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR` has any effect. Any idea? Just to be sure that I can build other .Net Core apps on MacOS with Nix I wrote an overlay to install version 2.2.401 of the SDK:

```
self: super: {
  dotnet-sdk = super.dotnet-sdk.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
    system = "x86_64-darwin";
    src = super.fetchurl {
      url = "https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/${version}/${super.dotnet-sdk.pname}-${version}-osx-x64.tar.gz";
      sha512 = "905FC6FB47B515BEC7A5624DABD5012518792B84BA05BA4BEE48F856563D653AC1421C2434A48803018DA30029288BDD8ECE289964528B9B11515E14F9C7E068";
    };
    meta.platforms = super.stdenv.lib.platforms.darwin;
    buildPhase = ''
      runHook preBuild
      echo -n "dotnet-sdk version: "
      ./dotnet --version
      runHook postBuild
    '';
  });
}
```

I was able to build the [F# language server](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharp-language-server) without problems without setting any environment variable. Even more weird, I downloaded version 3.0.101 of the SDK from the website and I can build FVim without problems with it

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/12894